# SLOW MYSQL UPDATE IN PHP (Section A shows Query, Section B shows Table Index, Section C shows Table Structure)

Tags: mysql, performance

WHY is the PHP script below taking forever to update until a timeout?  I am reading a csv file with ageing analysis data and saving the arrears amount into a database table in the appropriate ageing column. The table has 500k records and 152 columns as shown in Section C. The table index is shown in section B while the script is on section A

SECTION A (SLOW SQL)================================================================================
script snippet for each iteration in reading each csv file record:

```
    $age_bracket                = strtolower($age_bracket);
    $age_bracket                = str_replace('-','to',$age_bracket);
    $age_bracket                = str_replace(' ','',$age_bracket);
        
    $age_bracket_column         = "arrear_bracket_".$age_bracket;

    $sql                        = "UPDATE loan_book_backup

    SET ".$age_bracket_column." =  ".$amount_due."

    WHERE
      reporting_period            = 202211   AND
      arrangement_id              = '".$arrangement_id ."'";  
            
    $querySuccess     = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
```

SECTION B (Table Indexes)==========================================================================
loan_book_backup    0   PRIMARY 1   account_number  A   0   NULL    NULL        BTREE
loan_book_backup    0   PRIMARY 2   reporting_year  A   0   NULL    NULL        BTREE
loan_book_backup    0   PRIMARY 3   reporting_month A   0   NULL    NULL        BTREE
loan_book_backup    0   PRIMARY 4   portfolio_group A   0   NULL    NULL        BTREE
loan_book_backup    0   id  1   id  A   0   NULL    NULL        BTREE

SECTION C (Table Structure)========================================================================

```
THE DATABASE TABLE IS CALLED loan_book_bacckup and the structure is as follows:


id                          int(11) NO  UNI NULL    auto_increment  
arrangement_id                    varchar(15)   NO      NULL        
contract_type                     varchar(9)    NO      NULL        
portfolio_group                   varchar(20)   NO  PRI NULL        
portfolio_group1              varchar(20)   NO      NULL        
portfolio_group2              varchar(60)   NO      NULL        
product varchar(20)           NO        NULL        
sub_product                   varchar(22)   NO      NULL        
account_number                    bigint(20)    NO  PRI NULL        
customer_id                   mediumint(9)  NO      NULL        
customer_name                     varchar(30)   NO      NULL        
sme_rate                      varchar(5)    NO      NULL        
company_code                      varchar(11)   NO      NULL        
branch_code                   varchar(11)   NO      NULL        
branch_name                   varchar(11)   NO      NULL        
account_relationship_officer      varchar(21)   NO      NULL        
sector_code                   smallint(6)   NO      NULL        
industry_code                     smallint(6)   NO      NULL        
central_bank_sector_code      tinyint(4)    NO      NULL        
central_bank_sector_code_long     varchar(100)  NO      NULL        
currency_code                     varchar(3)    NO      NULL        
status                            varchar(3)    NO      NULL        
value_date                    int(11)           NO      NULL        
maturity_date                     int(11)           NO      NULL        
tenor                             int(11)           NO      NULL        
monthly_installment           double            NO      NULL        
current_principal             double            NO      NULL        
overdue_principal             double            NO      NULL        
overdue_interest              double            NO      NULL        
total_principal                   double            NO      NULL        
first_od_year                     mediumint(9)  NO      NULL        
first_od_date                     int(11)           NO      NULL        
last_credit_date              int(11)           NO      NULL        
date_last_moved                   int(11)           NO      NULL        
balance_foreign_current           double            NO      NULL        
exchange_rate                     decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
balance_local_current_year    double            YES     NULL    STORED GENERATED    
exposure_report_amount            double            NO      NULL        
balance_local_prior_year      double            NO      NULL        
balance_local_next_year           double            NO      NULL        
ifrs9_stage_month             int(11)           NO      NULL        
interest_rate                     decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
arrangement_fee                   decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
EIR                           decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
ecl_category                      varchar(15)   NO      NULL        
performing_status             varchar(15)   NO      NULL        
business_unit                     varchar(3)    NO      NULL        
business_unit_long            varchar(50)   NO      NULL        
BU                            varchar(3)    NO      NULL        
eng_status                    tinyint(1)    NO      NULL        
pd_segment                    varchar(30)   NO      NULL        
lgd_segment                   varchar(30)   NO      NULL        
sicr_flag                     tinyint(1)    YES     NULL        
IFRS9_stage_pre_qualitative   tinyint(4)    NO      NULL        
IFRS9_stage_risk_rating           varchar(20)   NO      NULL        
IFRS9_stage_current_year      tinyint(4)    YES     NULL    STORED GENERATED    
IFRS9_stage_next_period           tinyint(4)    NO      NULL        
IFRS9_stage_prior_year            tinyint(4)    NO      NULL        
IFRS9_stage_transition            varchar(15)   NO      NULL        
ead_curr_balance              double            NO      NULL        
write_off_indicator           tinyint(1)    NO      NULL        
closed_indicator              tinyint(1)    NO      NULL        
internal_grade_individual     varchar(100)  NO      NULL        
internal_grade_portfolio      varchar(100)  NO      NULL        
internal_grade_used           varchar(100)  NO      NULL        
s_and_p_grade                     varchar(20)   NO      NULL        
s_and_p_grade_desc            varchar(255)  NO      NULL        
fli_driver                    varchar(30)   NO      NULL        
pd_12_current_preFLI_individual   decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
pd_life_current_preFLI_individual decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
pd_12_current_preFLI_portfolio    decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
pd_life_current_preFLI_portfolio  decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
pd_type_used                      varchar(4)    NO      NULL        
individual_assessment_flag    varchar(1)    NO      NULL        
individual_assessment_comment     varchar(255)  NO      NULL        
pd_used_current_preFLI            decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
fli_pd12_adj                      decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
fli_pdlife_adj                    decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
fli_pd_adj                    decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
QA_general_economic           varchar(255)  NO      NULL        
QA_op_performance             varchar(255)  NO      NULL        
QA_covenant_breaches              varchar(10)   NO      NULL        
QA_contractual_terms_changed      varchar(30)   NO      NULL        
QA_liquidity                      varchar(30)   NO      NULL        
QA_credit_rating              varchar(30)   NO      NULL        
QA_payment_behavior           varchar(255)  NO      NULL        
QA_collateral_changes             varchar(255)  NO      NULL        
QA_comment                    varchar(255)  NO      NULL        
pd_sig_incr_flag              tinyint(1)    NO      NULL        
pd_12_current_postFLI             decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
pd_12_life_postFLI            decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
pd_used_prior_PostFLI             decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
pd_used_current_PostFLI           decimal(11,4) NO      NULL        
pd_change_from_prior              decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
coverage_ratio                    decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
haircut                           decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
disbursed_amount              double    NO      NULL        
disbursed_amount_local            double    NO      NULL        
facility_limit                    double    NO      NULL        
undrawn_amount                    double    NO      NULL        
ugd                           decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
collateral_amount             double    NO      NULL        
collateral_type                   varchar(50)   NO      NULL        
collateral_realisation_months     tinyint(4)    NO      NULL        
collateral_amount_discounted      double    NO      NULL        
reporting_period              int(11)   YES     NULL    STORED GENERATED    
reporting_year                    smallint(6)   NO  PRI NULL        
reporting_month                   int(11)   NO  PRI NULL        
pd_period                     int(11)   NO      NULL        
lgd_period                    int(11)   NO      NULL        
ead_period                    int(11)   NO      NULL        
reporting_date                    date          YES     NULL        
write_off_date                    int(11)   NO      NULL        
write_off_amount              double    NO      NULL        
pay_down_next_year            double    YES     NULL    STORED GENERATED    
pay_down_next_year_discounted     double    YES     NULL    STORED GENERATED    
dpd_ex_last_cr                    mediumint(9)  NO      NULL        
dpd_ex_first_od                   mediumint(9)  NO      NULL        
dpd_count_used                    mediumint(6)  NO      NULL        
dpd_bracket                   varchar(10)   NO      NULL        
dpd_class_terminos            varchar(15)   NO      NULL        
dpd_class_ifrs9                   varchar(15)   NO      NULL        
dpd_class_central_bank            varchar(20)   NO      NULL        
total_arrear_amount_original      double    NO      NULL        
total_arrear_amount_discount      double    NO      NULL        
new_old_indicator             varchar(3)    NO      NULL        
remaining_maturity_months     int(11)   NO      NULL        
default_month                     int(11)   NO      NULL        
month_on_book                     int(11)   NO      NULL        
default_counter_months            int(11)   NO      NULL        
cure_period_months            int(11)   NO      NULL        
cure_rate                     decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
total_arrears_foreign             double    NO      NULL        
total_arrears_local           double    NO      NULL        
lgd_current                   double    NO      NULL        
PV_FCL                            double    NO      NULL        
ECL_amount                    double    NO      NULL        
total_cashflows_discounted    double    NO      NULL        
discount_factor_cashflows     decimal(10,4) NO      NULL        
total_cashflows_original      double    NO      NULL        
npmt                              smallint(6)   NO      NULL        
ECL_remarks                   varchar(255)  NO      NULL        
npl_status                    varchar(30)   NO      NULL        
arrear_bracket_0to30              double    NO      NULL        
arrear_bracket_31to60             double    NO      NULL        
arrear_bracket_61to90             double    NO      NULL        
arrear_bracket_91to120            double    NO      NULL        
arrear_bracket_121to180           double    NO      NULL        
arrear_bracket_181to270           double    NO      NULL        
arrear_bracket_271to360           double    NO      NULL        
arrear_bracket_above360           double    NO      NULL        
created_at                    datetime  NO      current_timestamp()     


I am expecting a quick execution of the simply query
```

Comment: I hope those `DOUBLEs` don't give you rounding problems.  Currency should usually be stored in a `DECIMAL(m,n)` of suitable size.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.  In particular it shows the indexes.

For that update, the table needs this "composite" index:

```
INDEX(reporting_period, arrangement_id)
```